# Build tree from JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, tree

Given the following JSON Array:

```
    [{"ID":12,"NAME":"ktc","PARENTID":0},
     {"ID":11,"NAME":"root","PARENTID":0}, 
     {"ID":1,"NAME":"rwhitney","PARENTID":0},
     {"ID":21,"NAME":"shared folder","PARENTID":0}, 
     {"ID":2,"NAME":".config","PARENTID":1}, 
     {"ID":5,"NAME":"wallpapers","PARENTID":1}, 
     {"ID":3,"NAME":"geany","PARENTID":2}, 
     {"ID":4,"NAME":"colorschemes","PARENTID":3}, 
     {"ID":13,"NAME":"efast","PARENTID":12}, 
     {"ID":15,"NAME":"includes","PARENTID":13}, 
     {"ID":14,"NAME":"views","PARENTID":13}, 
     {"ID":17,"NAME":"css","PARENTID":15}, 
     {"ID":16,"NAME":"js","PARENTID":15}]
```

I need to build a menu tree with the subfolders nested beneath the parent folders.

Here is some server side code:

```
    socket.on('get-folders', function(data){
        var folders = [];
        getSession(session.key, function(currSession){
            db.rows('getFolders', currSession, [currSession.user], function(err, rows){
                if (err) {
                    socket.emit('err', 'Error is: ' + err );
                } else if(rows[0]){
                    //~ folders.push(JSON.stringify(rows));
                    socket.emit('get-folders', JSON.stringify(rows));
                    //~ n_Folders(rows, currSession, socket, folders, 0);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and client side:

```
    function rtnSocket(cmd, data, cb){
        socket.emit(cmd, data);
        socket.on(cmd, cb);
    }

    rtnSocket('get-folders', folderid, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

can someone please help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: it's usually better to use an existing library for this.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to learn the mechanics of a tree-like menu. And I don't want to use a library, if I can help it.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking it is for some real project. (I that case it would loose a lot of time).

Comment: Why do you need server side for a tree menu?

Comment: security, it is for a real project

Comment: its better to put the subFolders in inside the Parent Object as SubFolder Array 
.. it will eliminate ParentID and make easy to traverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all nodes from a flat data structure, use the `ID` and `PARENTID` as keys in a hash table and get the root array as result.

```js
var data = [{ ID: 12, NAME: "ktc", PARENTID: 0 }, { ID: 11, NAME: "root", PARENTID: 0 }, { ID: 1, NAME: "rwhitney", PARENTID: 0 }, { ID: 21, NAME: "shared folder", PARENTID: 0 }, { ID: 13, NAME: "efast", PARENTID: 12 }, { ID: 2, NAME: ".config", PARENTID: 1 }, { ID: 5, NAME: "wallpapers", PARENTID: 1 }, { ID: 15, NAME: "includes", PARENTID: 13 }, { ID: 14, NAME: "views", PARENTID: 13 }, { ID: 3, NAME: "geany", PARENTID: 2 }, { ID: 17, NAME: "css", PARENTID: 15 }, { ID: 16, NAME: "js", PARENTID: 15 }, { ID: 4, NAME: "colorschemes", PARENTID: 3 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.ID] = t[o.ID] || {}, o);
            t[o.PARENTID] = t[o.PARENTID] || {};
            t[o.PARENTID].children = t[o.PARENTID].children || [];
            t[o.PARENTID].children.push(t[o.ID]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, 0);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have opted for a single query which gets the results into a usable JSON object.  Before it was an array of objects and seemed clunky.

Comment: what does it mean? please edit the question, if necessary.

Comment: Nina, I just updated my question to reflect what I am using now.  I now need to convert the JSON into a visual hierarchical tree.  Can you offer any advice on that?

Comment: you could ask another question, because for a visual appearance, you need some style and i would need an example of it.

Comment: I tried asking another question, but it was almost closed immediately so I deleted it.  Apparently I'm no good at asking questions. :(

Comment: I think I am on to something anyway! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its better to put the subFolders in inside the Parent Object as SubFolder Array .. it will eliminate ParentID and make easy to traverse

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "NAME": "rwhitney",
    "PARENTID": 0,
    "SUB": [
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "NAME": ".config",
        "PARENTID": 1,
        "SUB": [
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "NAME": "geany",
            "PARENTID": 2,
            "SUB": [
              {
                "ID": 4,
                "NAME": "colorschemes",
                "PARENTID": 3
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ID": 5,
        "NAME": "wallpapers",
        "PARENTID": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The question was about *how* to do that.  Presumably the array structure supplied is available somewhere, and now there is a reason to convert it to a tree.

Answer (score 0):

At first we need to flat nested array:

```
const flatArray = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => {
        return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatArray(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
    }, []);
}
```

Then we can create a tree:

```
const makeTree = dataset => {
    let hashTable = Object.create(null)
    dataset.forEach( aData => hashTable[aData.ID] = { ...aData, childNodes : [] } )
    let dataTree = []
    dataset.forEach( aData => {
      if( aData.PARENTID ) hashTable[aData.PARENTID].childNodes.push(hashTable[aData.ID])
      else dataTree.push(hashTable[aData.ID])
    } )
    return dataTree
}
```

An example:

```js
let data = [
    [{ ID: 12, NAME: "ktc", PARENTID: 0 }, { ID: 11, NAME: "root", PARENTID: 0 }, { ID: 1, NAME: "rwhitney", PARENTID: 0 },
    { ID: 21, NAME: "shared folder", PARENTID: 0 }], [{ ID: 13, NAME: "efast", PARENTID: 12 }], [{ ID: 2, NAME: ".config", PARENTID: 1 },
    { ID: 5, NAME: "wallpapers", PARENTID: 1 }], [{ ID: 15, NAME: "includes", PARENTID: 13 }, { ID: 14, NAME: "views", PARENTID: 13 }],
    [{ ID: 3, NAME: "geany", PARENTID: 2 }], [{ ID: 17, NAME: "css", PARENTID: 15 }, { ID: 16, NAME: "js", PARENTID: 15 }],
    [{ ID: 4, NAME: "colorschemes", PARENTID: 3 }]];

const flatArray = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => {
        return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatArray(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
    }, []);
}

const makeTree = dataset => {
    let hashTable = Object.create(null)
    dataset.forEach( aData => hashTable[aData.ID] = { ...aData, childNodes : [] } )
    let dataTree = []
    dataset.forEach( aData => {
      if( aData.PARENTID ) hashTable[aData.PARENTID].childNodes.push(hashTable[aData.ID])
      else dataTree.push(hashTable[aData.ID])
    } )
    return dataTree
}
const dataTree = makeTree(flatArray(data));
console.log(dataTree)
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to answer my own question with the help of Nina above:

With the given JSON object - answer from Nina:

```
[{"ID":12,"NAME":"ktc","PARENTID":0},{"ID":11,"NAME":"root","PARENTID":0},{"ID":1,"NAME":"rwhitney","PARENTID":0},{"ID":21,"NAME":"shared folder","PARENTID":0},{"ID":2,"NAME":".config","PARENTID":1},{"ID":5,"NAME":"wallpapers","PARENTID":1},{"ID":3,"NAME":"geany","PARENTID":2},{"ID":4,"NAME":"colorschemes","PARENTID":3},{"ID":13,"NAME":"efast","PARENTID":12},{"ID":15,"NAME":"includes","PARENTID":13},{"ID":14,"NAME":"views","PARENTID":13},{"ID":17,"NAME":"css","PARENTID":15},{"ID":16,"NAME":"js","PARENTID":15},{"ID":27,"NAME":"images","PARENTID":16}]
```

I came up with this function:

```
var LHR= '',folderid = 0, parentid = 0;

    var seg = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    if(seg){
        LHR = seg.split('_')[0];
        folderid = seg.split('_')[1] || 0;
        //~ alert(folderid);
        parentid = seg.split('_')[2] || 0;
        if(isLike(LHR,['share']) == true){
            sharedFileID = LHR.split('-')[1];
        }
    }


LHR = LHR.replace(/%20/g,' ');
var MLHR = isLike(LHR, ['share']) == true ? LHR.split('-')[0] : LHR;
var folders = '';
function recurse(data, indent, limit){
  if(limit < 10){
    for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(folderid == data[i].ID){
            folders += '<div><input style="margin-left:60px" type="checkbox" data-id="'+folderid+'" data-name="' + data[i].NAME + '" class="check-folder tooltip">'+
                '<img style="margin-left:0px" data-pid="'+parentid+'" id="folder-'+folderid+'" src="/fa/folder-open.svg" class="blk tooltip"> ' + MLHR.replace(/%20/g,' ') + ' </div>';
        } else {
            folders += '<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:'+indent+'px" data-id="'+data[i].ID+'" data-name="' + data[i].NAME + '" class="check-folder tooltip">'+
                '<a style="margin-left:70px" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="dsp-ib w150 blk folders drop drag" draggable="true" droppable="true"  href="/dashboard/'+data[i].NAME+'_'+data[i].ID+'_'+data[i].PARENTID+'">'+
                '<img data-pid="'+data[i].PARENTID+'" src="/fa/folder.svg" class="fa ml--80 blk dsp-ib" id="folder-'+data[i].ID+'"> ' + data[i].NAME + '</a><br>';
        }
      if(data[i].children){
          recurse(data[i].children, indent+=20, ++limit);
      }
    }
  }

  $('#folders').html(folders);
}
```

and call it like thus:

```
recurse(data,0,0);
```

The function populates the tree of id "folders"

with the following output:

[image]

Thanks again for setting me on the right track!